# Bootstrap Scrollspy isn't working, doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been driving myself mad over getting ScrollSpy working. I have a menu that remains in a fixed, left position as the user scrolls down after a certain point, however, ScrollSpy refuses to work in any shape or form. I have tried a multitude of methods to get it working, as well as using a CMS (DotNetNuke) so please excuse some messy code here and there.

Here's the HTML of the nav:

```
    <div role="complementary" class="bs-docs-sidebar hidden-print" id="sideNav">
<div class="sideNavCont">
        <div>
        <span class="sideMenuHeading">TITLE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="sideMenuGuideSep"></div>
        <div class="sideMenu" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav nav-list affix sideMenuGuide">
            <li><a href="#opt1">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#opt2">Option 2</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#opt3">Option 3</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#opt4">Option 4</a> </li>
    (and so on...)
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the HTML for the content I want spied on:

```
<div id="content">
    <span id="opt1">
        <strong>Overview</strong>
    </span>
    <div>
         <strong>
             <span id="opt2" style="font-size: 32px;">TITLE</span>
          </strong>
    </div>
    <p>
         <span id="opt3" style="font-size: 32px;">
             <strong>TITLE</strong>
         </span>
   </p>
</div>
```

Plus I have this piece of Jquery:

```
    $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#content' });
```

Note that I also currently have working page anchors on each heading that work from linking from the nav.

I know the answer is probably staring me right in the face, but I'd appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Is `#content` the element you want to spy on and `#sideNav`the bootstrap nav component?

Comment: Yep, that's right. #sideNav is the container for the nav, whereas .sideMenu is the actual component (or at least the parent of the ul element).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the bootstrap doc, http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy. 
"Then add the data-target attribute with the ID or class of the parent element of any Bootstrap .nav component."

So it should probably be initialized like this:

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#sideNav' })
```

Comment: I already tried this, but it works when I discovered a bit of idiocy on my behalf. I assumed that Bootstrap had a default style for active li elements, as it does with hover effects. I was wrong, and had to make a style myself. Clearly I have a lot to learn about Bootstrap!
Thanks a lot for your help!